# Executar comando para cada arquivo em um diretório no MS-DOS

Tags: ms-dos

Estou fazendo um pequeno bat para quebrar um galho sobre uma aplicação que estou montando, onde ele deve executar scripts sql dentro do banco MySQL. O problema é que tenho que editar esse bat toda vez que eu inserir um novo script e isso acaba ficando chato...

Existe alguma forma de fazer com que, através do prompt eu possa pegar o nome de todos os arquivos dentro de uma pasta e, a partir disso executar um comando no prompt para cada arquivo?

Comment: Qual comando você vai sumonar no prompt?

Comment: mysql -u root < %cd%\scripts\ **nome_do_arquivo.sql**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se precisar fazer um script mais incremento no futuro pode usar o powershell, a linha abaixo retorna os nomes de todos os arquivos na pasta especificada.

```
(Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6"  -File).Name
```

Para um script com menu e opção de qual arquivo selecionar segue um exemplo:

```
$arquivos = (Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data"  -File).Name
Write-Host "Arquivos encontrados:"
Write-Host "99 - para executa todos."
$i = 0
foreach($item in $arquivos){
    Write-Host $i "-" $item
    $i++
}

$opcao = Read-Host "selecione uma opção: "

if($opcao -eq 99){
    Write-Host "executar todos os arquivos"
}else{
    Write-Host "Arquivo selecionado " $arquivos[$opcao]
}
```

O resultado no terminal é

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem algum problema a resposta?

Comment: na verdade não preciso disso, e mesmo assim tenho que considerar que só temos o powershell nativo no windows 8 pra frente se não me engano... também não preciso de menu, só preciso que ele leia os arquivos na pasta e em seguida execute eles no MySQL

Comment: @LeandroLUK o powershell está disponível na versão 2 para XP e vista, o V3 pode ser instalado no windows 7 e já vem instalado no 8 e 2012. Essa informação esta na [documentação](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb978526.aspx) próximo ao final da página.

Comment: ok, entendo vou dar uma lida utilizando o exemplo que vc me passou...

Answer (score 4):

Uma possibilidade é usar o FOR:

```
FOR %a IN (*) DO echo %a
```

A sintaxe acima é para executar direto no CMD. Para usar em .bat use dois `%`:

```
FOR %%a IN (*) DO echo %%a
```

Substitua o `echo` pelo comando desejado, e acrescente os parâmetros que desejar. No lugar do `*` você pode especificar as *wildcards* normais do sistema, para nome e extensão do arquivo.

Se quiser fazer alguma operação com a listagem em arquivos texto, você pode obter os nomes do diretório assim:

```
DIR *.* /b > listagem.txt
```

A flag /b é para pegar o caminho do arquivo. Use a flag /s se quiser incluir subdiretórios.

Comment: poderia me passar um exemplo usando o comando *mysql -u root < %cd%\scripts\nome_do_arquivo.sql* ? lembrando que antes eu preciso pegar o nome dele com o for que vc informou...

Comment: @LeandroLUK seu problema é completamente diferente do que você perguntou. Se precisa executar vários sqls dentro do MySQL, não faz sentido depender do .bat. Mas se for fazer com bat mesmo assim, é mais ou menos isso: `FOR %a IN (*) DO mysql -u root <  %a` só que vai ter que por a senha em aberto.